# Firebase app with reused package name records no data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I removed one firebase app and had to create a new one with the same package name within the same firebase project. Debugging for both debug and release builds works well in firebase console's debugview. But i don't see any records in the analytics dashboard for days.

Did anyone experience the same mystery? Can I solve it by myself or do I have to contact the Firebase Support?

I cannot change any package names since they are allready set up in play store.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How long did you wait for the data to show up in the charts? Debug view will show data instantly, but the charts may take up to a day to refresh. See firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html

Comment: It looks like a bug. I'd recommend to contact Firebase Support for it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your advice, but i was waiting for the records to show up for more than a day.

Comment: It really was an internal firebase bug. But it is solved now. Hopefully not only in my case. ;-)